# Selenium send keys to log in box not working

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to log in to my draftkings account with selenium, but I am having trouble inputting my email and password.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.draftkings.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/ul/li[3]/a").click()
```

## throws an error

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='Username']").send_keys('username')
```

## does nothing

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='Username']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'username')",elem)
```

Comment: Have you considered using `find_element_by_link_text()` to click the Sign-in link? There are 4 elements with `id=Username` on the page. You want the 3rd one. Get all of them and then access the 3rd element in that collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me below is working-Use index in xpath.

```
#Click Sign In Button
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/ul/li[3]/a").click()
#Type Username
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='Username'])[3]").send_keys("Username")
#Type Password
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='Password'])[2]").send_keys("Password")
#Click Submit button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='login_section']//a[@class='dk-btn dk-btn-success'])[2]").click()
```

Comment: Instead of using `time.sleep`, you'd better to use `WebDriverWait(...)`.

Comment: @ falsetru Thanks, let the OP  do it- i just answered the *problem* and hinted for change..

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to provide a solution that uses best practices? Take 60 seconds and replace the `sleep()` with a `wait`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, The page has 4 elements with id `Username`.

You need to filter one out of them:

```
for x in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#Username"):
    if x.is_displayed():
        x.send_keys('username')
        break
```

Comment: Yes it is kind of  brute-force!

Comment: @SIslam, I couldn't find proper xpath/css selector that does not involve hard-coded index that is simpler that the one in the answer.

Comment: Pitfall of not hardcoding in case of dom selection may entail unexpected result. I  figured today while experimenting.

Comment: @SIslam, I don't understand what you mean. Showing concrete example will be helpful. IMHO, if the web page change the layout, hard-coded index cause more problems. ;)